# Error: please supply starting values

Tags: r, error-handling, regression, glm

I am conducting a log binomial regression in R. I want to control for covariates in the model (age and BMI- both continuous variables) whereas the dependent variable is Outcome(Yes or No) and independent variable is Group (1 or 2).

```
fit<-glm(Outcome~Group, data=data.1, family=binomial(link="log"))
```

and it works fine.

When I try putting age in the model, it still works fine. 
However, when I put BMI in the model, it gives me the following:

```
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
```

I have been tried different combination of starting values such as:

`fit<-glm(Outcome~Group+Age+BMI, data=data.1, family=binomial(link="log"), start=c(0,0,0,0)` or even start=(1,4) or start =4 but it still gives me the error.

It also says:

```
Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  length of 'start' should equal 4 and correspond to initial coefs for c("(Intercept)", "group1", "age", "bmi")
```

.

Any help on this will be much appreciated!

Edited: adding reproducible example.

```
N=50
data.1=data.frame(Outcome=sample(c(0,0,1),N, rep=T),Age=runif(N,8,58),BMI=rnorm(N,25,6),
                  Group=rep(c(0,1),length.out=N))
data.1$Group<-as.factor(data.1$Group)
fit<-glm(Outcome~Group, data=data.1, family=binomial(link="log"))
coefini=coef(glm(Outcome~Group+Age+BMI, data=data.1,family =binomial(link = "logit") ))
fit<-glm(Outcome~Group+Age+BMI, data=data.1, family=binomial(link="log"),start=coefini)
```

Comment: What is the `typeof(data.1$BMI)`?

Comment: Why are you using a log link instead of a logit?

Comment: typeof(data,1$BMI) is double.

Comment: I am using a log link instead of logit because I want the relative risk estimate and not the odds ratio. Is that the right way to go?

Comment: Look at the comments of this post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8661/logistic-regression-in-r-odds-ratio, it appears that the OR is the better way to model.

Answer (score 9):

After some trial and error, using `set.seed(123)`:

```
coefini=coef(glm(Outcome~Group+Age, data=data.1,family =binomial(link = "log") ))
fit2<-glm(Outcome~Group+Age+BMI, data=data.1, family=binomial(link="log"),start=c(coefini,0))

summary(fit2)

Call:
glm(formula = Outcome ~ Group + Age + BMI, family = binomial(link = "log"), 
    data = data.1, start = c(coefini, 0))

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.2457  -0.9699  -0.7725   1.2737   1.6799  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -1.5816964  1.0616813  -1.490    0.136
Group1       0.4987848  0.3958399   1.260    0.208
Age          0.0091428  0.0138985   0.658    0.511
BMI         -0.0005498  0.0331120  -0.017    0.987

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 65.342  on 49  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 63.456  on 46  degrees of freedom
AIC: 71.456

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

Comment: Thank you both for this question and answer! I had been trying to use R to test associations with a binomial outcome variable with a log link function and also kept getting that "no valid set..." error. It looks like this solution works for me too.

Comment: Upvoted both. I don't think it'll let me upvote again. :)