# Can't fit the Negative Binomial regression to log-data

Tags: r, regression, transformation, poisson

I am working with high-dimensional count data, I have first fitted a Poisson regression in which the explanatory variables are log-transformed. I wanted to do the same with the Negative Binomial regression but I get this error:

```
model_nb<- glm.nb(m~log.transformed.counts, link="identity") 
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
```

Comment: Identity-link count models are often numerically unstable/hard to fit.  Can you explain why you're using an identity link? Can we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342637/error-please-supply-starting-values

Comment: if I put as link the log I get this error message: Error in glm.fitter(x = X, y = Y, w = w, etastart = eta, offset = offset,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
In addition: Warning message:
step size truncated due to divergence"

Comment: OK, probably can't answer this without a [mcve] (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example ) ...